# Displaying a list(array) in a particular order in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to display a list of items in ASP.NET MVC view using Razor's **foreach** helper:

```
@foreach(var item in items)
{
<div class="...">@item.SomeProp </div>
}
```

The **items** is a list of objects with particular properties. I need to display them in a particular order. What I am currently doing is I have property called Order in the object and then manually assign value to it according to some order but was wondering if there are better solutions.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try the OrderBy extension method  ? `items.OrderBy(f=>f.SomeProperty)` ?

Comment: So what is the problem then ?

Comment: @Shyju Hi. I know how to order the items... E.g we have an object with property Order. Somewhere in a backend I assign a list of items like this:
Item1.Order = 1, Item2.Order = 3, Items3.Order = 2. Later I order the objects by Order property(using ext method) so when displayed they would be in this order:
    * Item1
    * Item3
    * Item2
My question was if there are ways to display them without having this additional Order property. I hope I was clear...

Comment: The list could be quite big so I dont really wanna manually set the order for each element. Probably I am asking something impossible but was wondering maybe someone had same challenge )

Answer (score 0):

It might be the same as what you mentioned with your Order property, but the last time I needed to do this, I added a property to my Model object that was readonly. Something like this (obviously pseudocode):

```
public List<whateverObjectGoesHere> OrderedList 
{
    get 
    {
        //Sort list somehow
        return orderedList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically I am trying to display a table with rows in a particular order using only loops